# Is there a MIME type on Android Studio for 3-D object files (aka .obj)?

Tags: android, 3d, firebase-storage, mime-types

I'm trying to upload a 3-d object file to Firebase Storage through Android Studio. I have to create a method that first opens a file chooser however I need to have a MIME type set in order to retrieve the obj file on the emulator. I've tried to do it without setting a type and the program just crashes out and I've tried to put the string "application/obj" but that did nothing. Please help.

```
private void openOBJFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType(/*DON'T KNOW WHAT MIME TYPE TO PUT HERE/*);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [IANA registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) includes several media types for 3-D model files, many of which begin with `model/`.  Examples include:

- `model/obj` and `model/mtl` for Wavefront object and material files.
- `model/gltf+json` for glTF.

Comment: This didn't work however I just used `application/*` and I was able to grab the obj file